# Can I stop mobs from walking into my house... without a door?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm building a castle in Minecraft survival mode. It's a big structure and a tiny door would look ridiculous, so instead I have a 5x7 hole in the wall. The castle is mob proof but the outside isn't - I don't mind some creepers spawning outside, but I definitely don't want them walking inside!

**Is there any way I can stop a mob from pathfinding, without blocking the path for myself?** Something like placing [double carpets on the floor](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/gefwnb/mobs_and_villagers_can_not_path_find_or_walk/) would be perfect... but it doesn't work on Bedrock 1.16.20, I guess it's a Java edition feature.

Taking a different approach would be ok, but this is the only entrance to my base so I'll be using it *a lot*, which means it has to be:

- Instantaneous - no piston doors or bridges.
- Effortless to use - no jumping / flying / slime launching over a moat or a trench.
- Painless - no magma blocks or walking through a lava cascade. Although the cascade would be cool :)

Is there anything I can build, or do I have to lower my requirements?

PS: I'm not worried only about creepers (cats would do for that I guess?), I want to stop all mobs, or at least, all the hostile ones... well, except phantoms, nothing I can do about those.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried a lot just to get this to work, but pathfinding is different in BE, meaning some things that would normally work in JE (like the carpet trick) wouldn't work Here's a slightly different approach that might tickle your fancy.
[image: Interesting idea ExpertCoder14!]
Walking into your base, you have a line of open trapdoors in the floor with a lava pit underneath. Try building the setup below, then try to get inside without jumping or sprinting.

If you test it a few times, you'll find out that just by holding down your forward key, you can make it across just by walking! No sprinting, no jumping. Just hold <kbd>W</kbd> and go.

As long as you don't stop in the middle of the crossing, you should be just fine. Mobs are too slow to make it through! So they fall and die in the lava.

You can walk in at angles of up to 45 degrees. Anything more and it heightens the risk of falling in.

I suggest, instead of creating just a lava pit, you can funnel mobs into a custom-built mob grinder so you can get their experience. This also helps because you can implement a minecart system that allows players to safely escape the funnel without falling in with the mobs.

### Downsides

- **Slimes:** Slimes are so big, they won't fit in the pitfall trap!
- **Witches:** They drink potions to self-heal. Depending on your mob grinder method, they might take a while to die!

Comment: Interesting... I'll give it a try tomorrow. I think my mob grinder might just be a 60 blocks fall into the lava :D. That should also give me enough time to activate my parachute in case I fall. Slimes don't spawn anywhere near me. Spiders do... but they are mostly harmless.

Comment: It _almost_ works. I tried it with a couple of zombies, skeletons and creepers, all walking almost perpendicular to the trap. They all fell in the trap, except for one of the creepers, who was able to walk over it.

Comment: @AJPerez You were talking about ocelots and cats in your original question. You could put some of them on a lead and attach them to a fence nearby your base entrance.

Answer (score 1):

Railway. Mobs won't go onto railway unless pushed, by them or others.
Looks like some of the old methods no longer work in newer versions.
Or a honey block moat. Non leathal and you can jump over it.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. I tested it in Bedrock Edition (which this question is asking for, mind you) and the mobs walk over the rails and attack their targets.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you might want to interest yourself in transparent blocks like glass or glowstone, as this prevents nearby mobs from slowly wandering and selecting blocks to travel inside your build. However it is more on an impractical approach as you'd have to replace a fifty block radius on the floor that would normally be grass or dirt. I am currently working on other solutions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well... maybe not the whole area around the castle, that would be impractical, but maybe a few blocks around the gate. Glass and glowstone wouldn't look good, but I believe tree leaves are transparent blocks too; that could work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but for anyone else who finds themselves wondering, from what I have been able to tell all the usual mobs (hostile and passive) except for medium and small slimes will not jump onto a block of scaffolding that has a piece of carpet on top. The front of the scaffolding has to be visible, which makes it to where it is not the prettiest of solutions. However, with this trick working for the majority of mobs, I would say it’s well worth it. The only test I can think of that I have not done is seeing if it works for nether mobs too. [image] [image]